# Simple routing issue - Signup, login, logout, "no route matchs GET '/Signup'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have setup a Signup, Login, Logout with `bcrypt`.  I have set up basic routing as shown below however keep getting the same error with

> "no route matches GET '/Signup'"...

anyone, please help I'm confused - '/Signup' should go to sessions#new which is new.html.erb in sessions right?  Please clarify...  There might also be something wrong with my controllers which I will post if necessary as well.

Thanks for any help.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :users, controller: :sessions
root 'users#index'

get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
get '/signup', to: 'users#update'
post '/signup', to: 'users#create'


get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

Comment: Be careful the URL is partially case sensitive. Especially what resides after domain name. (I say this because your signup is capitalized in your URL). Also same route points to two different actions in your routing.

Comment: In addition to the issues pointed out by @Maxence, you've got `/signup` pointed to actions in your UsersController, not your SessionsController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, if you use `resources :users` then you don't need to declare again these lines on the `routes.rb` file

```
get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
get '/signup', to: 'users#update'
post '/signup', to: 'users#create'
```

because `resources :users` providing all of these like after

```
resources :users
```

then `rake routes`

```
 users GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)             users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)    users#edit
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
             PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)         users#destroy
```

this `new_user_path` for `Signup` form and `users_path` `post` method is user create route, so for signup you have to use `users` controller.

Same as for `sessions` and `login` after use `resources :sessions` instead of three lines yours, you can get after `rake routes`

```
    sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)          sessions#index
             POST   /sessions(.:format)          sessions#create
 new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)      sessions#new
edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format) sessions#edit
     session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#show
             PATCH  /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#update
             PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#update
             DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#destroy
```

For login you can use `sessions` controller, for `sessions` only `create` and `destroy` you can more specific your `sessions` route like just edit `sessions` route

```
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

you can get now only three routes for `sessions` like `new`,`create`&`destroy`

```
   sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)         sessions#create
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)     sessions#new
    session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)     sessions#destroy
```

For **Signup form** `users/new.html.erb` and for **Login form** `sessions/new.html.erb`

You can follow the [`Michael Hartl`](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up) tutorial for basic authentication understand.

Answer (score 0):

To create a singular resource, you must specify:

HTTP Verb -  Path - Controller#Action

e.g. `get '/signup', to: 'controller#action'`

You need know what is the controller and action responsible for create the new user and then replace **controller#action**.

For more details about routes look [rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).